# I get exception when using Thread.sleep(x) or wait()

Tags: java, sleep

I have tried to delay - or put to sleep - my Java program, but an error occurs.

I'm unable to use `Thread.sleep(x)` or `wait()`. The same error message appears:

> unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Is there any step required before using the `Thread.sleep()` or `wait()` methods?

Comment: Well, this is popular.  There must be an enormous number of people who need to delay their Java program for a few seconds.  Hard to imagine.  Of course, putting the correct title on the post would help immensely.

Answer (score 576, accepted):

You have a lot of reading ahead of you. From compiler errors through exception handling, threading and thread interruptions. But this will do what you want:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i able to run it.. beside, what is the use for catch(interruptedException ex)

Comment: See reply from Abel. Google for InterruptedException. Making a long story short: The thread can be interrupted while sleeping, and this is a kind of exception which needs to be explicitly handled.

Comment: Some answers tell to do nothing on the exception, some say to throw, this tells to interrupt(). Would someone care to discuss which is appropriate and why?

Comment: @Suma There plenty discussion on it, including Stack Overflow itself. Just search for it. Too long for a comment. After a few years, the only answer I have is: it depends. Usually the ideal solution is to terminate whatever the thread is doing gracefully (e.g. roll back this transaction, break a loop etc.), but that's very context dependent.

Comment: so than what is a timer for? could you achieve the same functionality with a timer? I read the java doc, and it mentioned something about delays, but being a newbie with code, im about to finish my second year of high school programming, Im not entirely sure if the delay it talks about would be useful here, or even the right class to use

Comment: @JohnnyCoder Thread.sleep pauses the current thread. Timer allows delayed execution of a task on a different thread.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but i think [the solution by Boris E Spider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-to-delay-in-java) , to a duplicate post, is better.

Answer (score 195):

As other users have said you should surround your call with a `try{...} catch{...}` block. But since Java 1.5 was released, there is TimeUnit class which do the same as **Thread.sleep(millis)** but is more convenient.
You can pick time unit for sleep operation.

```
try {
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(100);
    TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(100);
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(100);
    TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(100);
    TimeUnit.DAYS.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //Handle exception
}
```

Also it has additional methods: 
[TimeUnit Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)

Comment: See other answers for example of how to surround these calls with the required `try-catch` exception handling.

Comment: Dont forget " import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;"

Answer (score 29):

Have a look [at this excellent brief post](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/sleep.html) on how to do this properly.

Essentially: catch the [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html). Remember that you must add this catch-block. The post explains this a bit further.

Answer (score 13):

Use the following coding construct to handle exceptions

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    //Handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Put your `Thread.sleep` in a try catch block

```
try {
    //thread to sleep for the specified number of milliseconds
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch ( java.lang.InterruptedException ie) {
    System.out.println(ie);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

When using **Android** (the only time when I use Java) I would recommend using a handler instead putting the thread to sleep.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "I've waited for two hole seconds to show this!");

        }
    }, 2000);
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: This is for Android not for Core Java

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
try{

    Thread.sleep(100);
}catch(Exception e)
{
   System.out.println("Exception caught");
}
```

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to catch `Exception` in Java?

Comment: Better catch     InterruptedException like the other answers here

Comment: This is called a 'Pokemon Exception Handler' - gotta catch em all.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  //type code


  short z=1000;
  Thread.sleep(z);/*will provide 1 second delay. alter data type of z or value of z for longer delays required */

  //type code
}
```

eg:-

```
class TypeCasting {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    short f = 1;
    int a = 123687889;
    short b = 2;
    long c = 4567;
    long d=45;
    short z=1000;
    System.out.println("Value of a,b and c are\n" + a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c + "respectively");
    c = a;
    b = (short) c;
    System.out.println("Typecasting...........");
    Thread.sleep(z);
    System.out.println("Value of B after Typecasting" + b);
    System.out.println("Value of A is" + a);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My ways to add delay to a Java program.

```
public void pause1(long sleeptime) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        //ToCatchOrNot
    }
}

public void pause2(long sleeptime) {
    Object obj = new Object();
    if (sleeptime > 0) {
        synchronized (obj) {
            try {
                obj.wait(sleeptime);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //ToCatchOrNot
            }
        }
    }
}
public void pause3(long sleeptime) {
    expectedtime = System.currentTimeMillis() + sleeptime;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < expectedtime) {
        //Empty Loop   
    }
}
```

This is for sequential delay but for Loop delays refer to [Java Delay/Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586137/java-delay-wait).

Comment: Please note that blatant self-promotion is not allowed here. See [the last point here in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). You can, however, put the link in your profile - that is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to wait is to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which returns the number of milliseconds since midnight on January 1, 1970 UTC. For example, to wait 5 seconds:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //some code
    long original = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (true) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis - original >= 5000) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //more code after waiting
}
```

This way, you don't have to muck about with threads and exceptions.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This consumes CPU while waiting.

Comment: @yacc This is true, but it is simpler than using threads and doesn't use too much CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

Sleep for one second or

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
```

Sleep for a minute.

As this is a loop, this presents an inherent problem - drift. Every time you run code and then sleep you will be drifting a little bit from running, say, every second. If this is an issue then don't use `sleep`.

Further, `sleep` isn't very flexible when it comes to control.

For running a task every second or at a one second delay I would **strongly** recommend a [`ScheduledExecutorService`][1] and either [`scheduleAtFixedRate`][2] or [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`][3].

To run the method `myTask` every second (Java 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(App::myTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static void myTask() {
    System.out.println("Running");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep()` is simple for the beginners and may be appropriate for unit tests and proofs of concept.

But please **DO NOT** use `sleep()` for production code. Eventually `sleep()` may bite you badly.

Best practice for multithreaded/multicore java applications to use the "thread wait" concept. Wait releases all the locks and monitors held by the thread, which allows other threads to acquire those monitors and proceed while your thread is sleeping peacefully.

Code below demonstrates that technique:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class DelaySample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       DelayUtil d = new DelayUtil();
       System.out.println("started:"+ new Date());
       d.delay(500);
       System.out.println("half second after:"+ new Date());
       d.delay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); 
       System.out.println("1 minute after:"+ new Date());
    }
}
```

`DelayUtil` implementation:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class DelayUtil {
    /** 
    *  Delays the current thread execution. 
    *  The thread loses ownership of any monitors. 
    *  Quits immediately if the thread is interrupted
    *  
    * @param durationInMillis the time duration in milliseconds
    */
   public void delay(final long durationInMillis) {
      delay(durationInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }

   /** 
    * @param duration the time duration in the given {@code sourceUnit}
    * @param unit
    */
    public void delay(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long deadline = currentTime+unit.toMillis(duration);
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition waitCondition = lock.newCondition();

        while ((deadline-currentTime)>0) {
            try {
                lock.lockInterruptibly();    
                waitCondition.await(deadline-currentTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with threads, try this method:

```
public static void pause(int seconds){
    Date start = new Date();
    Date end = new Date();
    while(end.getTime() - start.getTime() < seconds * 1000){
        end = new Date();
    }
}
```

It starts when you call it, and ends when the number of seconds have passed.

Comment: This would consume CPU during the sleep time. On Thread.sleep() the thread can be descheduled.

Comment: you are ridi and there is no water :D

Comment: user2276378 had misunderstood the question's English. OP said he was "unable to used sleep or wait" which user2276378 thought to mean that he could not use them (or wasn't allowed to use them) and so he provided a *valid* solution that did not use sleep or wait. Try not to be too harsh English isn't everyone's first language.