# Java Delay/Wait

Tags: java, loops, delay, wait, notify

How do I delay a while loop to 1 second intervals without slowing down the entire code / computer it's running on to the one second delay (just the one little loop).

Comment: _without slowing down the entire code_ elaborate this

Comment: @JigarJoshi I'm trying to delay this while loop at 1 second intervals for my Minecraft plugin. But most of the wait methods pause the entire server for the set time, rather than just the loop

Comment: you want the execution of while loop for a fixed period of time and then again in fixed delay.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```java
Thread.sleep(1000); // do nothing for 1000 miliseconds (1 second)
```

Comment: Won't this pause the whole script/computer?

Comment: This would just pause that particular thread in which this code is running. your computer won't get freezed

Answer (score 12):

It seems your loop runs on Main thread and if you do `sleep` on that thread it will pause the app (since there is only one thread which has been paused), to overcome this you can put this code in new `Thread` that runs parallely

```
try{

  Thread.sleep(1000);
}catch(InterruptedException ex){
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6):

My simple ways to delay a loop.

I already put the codes here after failing to follow the stackoverflow's standards.

```
//1st way: Thread.sleep : Less efficient compared to 2nd
try {
  while (true) {//Or any Loops
   //Do Something
   Thread.sleep(sleeptime);//Sample: Thread.sleep(1000); 1 second sleep
  }
 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
   //SomeFishCatching
 }
//================================== Thread.sleep


//2nd way: Object lock waiting = Most efficient due to Object level Sync.
Object obj = new Object();
 try {
  synchronized (obj) {
   while (true) {//Or any Loops
   //Do Something
   obj.wait(sleeptime);//Sample obj.wait(1000); 1 second sleep
   }
  }
 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
   //SomeFishCatching
 }
//=============================== Object lock waiting

//3rd way:  Loop waiting = less efficient but most accurate than the two.
long expectedtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (true) {//Or any Loops
   while(System.currentTimeMillis() < expectedtime){
     //Empty Loop   
   }
   expectedtime += sleeptime;//Sample expectedtime += 1000; 1 second sleep
   //Do Something
}
//===================================== Loop waiting
```

Comment: I like the third way, because it can inhibit a whole cpu core and no one would _ever_ call this a code smell.

Comment: Another advantage of the third method is it does not require additional try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

As Jigar has indicated you can use another Thread to do work which can operate, sleep etc independently of other Threads.  The `java.util.Timer` class might help you as well since it can perform periodic tasks for you without you having to get into multithreaded programming.