# Java Time Interval

Tags: java

There is code like :

```
System.out.println("I wanna print next statement after 5 seconds");
// 5 seconds later
System.out.println("Time to show !");
```

How could I realize that? please give me an answer. ( // 5 seconcds later)

Comment: you must use a thread
watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYN-CBtPNiM

Comment: You can use a `Timer` or `Thread.sleep()`, But I really recommend Timer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Delay/Wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586137/java-delay-wait)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(numberOfMilliseconds)` is the way to make the current thread wait for a given amount of time.  If you need to fire off something that should be done in 5 seconds, but don't want to stall the entire application, look into `TimerTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);    
}catch (InterruptedException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds

Thread.sleep is a static method telling the 
current thread to sleep for N milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 try {
   Thread.sleep( 5000 );
 } catch ( InterruptedException ex) { }
```

Comment: sorry, my fault. i forgot the exception object.

Comment: BTW - the choice of `wakeAndContinue` is because I feel that every `catch` should either dump the stack trace, re-throw it, log it or ignore it with an *explanation as to why.*  The nomenclature is my (very non standard) way to indicate 'ignore'.  ;)

Comment: yes, pretty nice. but in a perfekt world every catch should have a handling.