# Short sleep till Click function

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sleep

I´ve got a quiz app where the user can answer some questions with radio buttons. Only one answer is correct.

When I click on my button to show the right answer, it is shown in a textView.

Until now I have another button to navigate to the next question.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
...

}
```

Now I want to change that. When the user press the button for showing the right question, I want the app 5 seconds to sleep and then navigate to the next question.
How can I handle that?

Comment: The answer to this question might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342651/how-to-delay-or-sleep-a-java-program-in-few-second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the app 5 seconds to sleep and then navigate to the next question.

Use the [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class. Simply call `postDelayed()` to execute the code you want in five seconds.

---

Every View already has a Handler so try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something
            }
        }, 5000);
}
```

This will execute the code inside `run()` 5 seconds after the Button has been clicked.