# How can I delay the time between two method calls?

Tags: java, user-interface, timer

i am writing a program where i shutdown the system after a message box has been shown containing this text, "You have 60 seconds until system shutdown",

but i want to wait 60 seconds after this box shows to run the run time, after hours of research i  cant figure out how to do this, nor can my AP-Programming teacher...

Can anyone help me please?

I'm doing this in a GUI so i think in need a swing timer, but I'm not sure.

this is what i have-

```
    private void Shutdown() throws IOException {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have 60 seconds until system shutdown");
     timer = new Timer(60,);
    Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 60");
}

private void Logoff() throws IOException {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have 60 seconds until system logoff");
    timer = new Timer(60, )
    Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -l -t 60");
```

i am calling these methods from my button click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342651/how-can-i-delay-a-java-program-for-a-few-seconds

Comment: Best way is to use Timer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java , `Thread.sleep` should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Check also the [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)`

Answer (score 2):

User a `javax.swing.Timer`. A really simple example is the following:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(60000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /* perform shutdown */
    }
});

timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shutting down in 60 seconds...");

timer.stop(); // <- optionally cancels the count
```

Since JOptionPane dialogs are modal you can take advantage of that if you want and stop the timer when the show method returns. That will cancel the countdown.

Also since they are modal if you really want to use sleep you will have to start a new thread to do it:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        /* perform shutdown */
    }
}).start();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shutting down in 60 seconds...");
```

I would recommend Timer over sleep because it is much more flexible. The following is a short JDialog example that provides count down feedback to the user and a 'proper' cancel button:

```
public class TimerDialog extends JDialog {

    private static final String BEGIN_MSG = "Shutting down in ";
    private static final String END_MSG = " seconds...";

    private int count = 60;

    private JLabel message = new JLabel(BEGIN_MSG + count + END_MSG);

    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (--count > 0) {
                message.setText(BEGIN_MSG + count + END_MSG);
            } else {
                endCount();
                performShutdown();
            }
        }
    });

    private TimerDialog() {
        setModal(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                endCount();
            }
        });

        message.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
        message.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                endCount();
            }
        });

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.add(cancel);

        content.add(message, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setContentPane(content);
        pack();

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void beginCount() {
        timer.start();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void endCount() {
        timer.stop();
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }

    private void performShutdown() {
        /* perform shutdown */
    }

    public static void showAndCountDown() {
        new TimerDialog().beginCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: At least for me javax.swing.Timer worked much better than Thread.sleep, since it opens a separate thread.