# How do I make a delay in Java?

Tags: java, wait, sleep, thread-sleep

I am trying to do something in Java and I need something to wait / delay for an amount of seconds in a while loop.

```
while (true) {
    if (i == 3) {
        i = 0;
    }

    ceva[i].setSelected(true);

    // I need to wait here

    ceva[i].setSelected(false);

    // I need to wait here

    i++;
}
```

I want to build a step sequencer.

How do I make a delay in Java?

Comment: Use `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: Consider to use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: What is the purpose of waiting? Are you waiting for a certain event to happen? Make sure you understand what [sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) method does

Comment: @Tiny, it's NOT safe.

Comment: It is actually `Thread.sleep(<milisecondsToSleep>)`. The `s` shouldn't be capitalized.

Answer (score 1140, accepted):

If you want to pause then use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

To sleep for one second or

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
```

To sleep for a minute.

As this is a loop, this presents an inherent problem - drift. Every time you run code and then sleep you will be drifting a little bit from running, say, every second. If this is an issue then don't use `sleep`.

Further, `sleep` isn't very flexible when it comes to control.

For running a task every second or at a one second delay I would **strongly** recommend a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and either [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) or [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

For example, to run the method `myTask` every second (Java 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(App::myTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static void myTask() {
    System.out.println("Running");
}
```

And in Java 7:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myTask();
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static void myTask() {
    System.out.println("Running");
}
```

Comment: @Matthew Moisen I couldn't get this Java 8 example to run. What is App:: exactly? By changing myTask() to a runnable lambda it works: Runnable myTask = () -> {...};

Comment: It's a method reference @comfytoday - I suggest starting with [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: `TimeUnit.SECONDS.wait(1)` is throwing `IllegalMonitorStateException` in Java 8.1 build 31 on Windows 6.3.  Instead, I'm able to use `Thread.sleep(1000)` without a try/catch.

Comment: You called `wait` not `sleep` @JohnMeyer. Be more careful.

Comment: In Java 8, in java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit you get ```Unhandled exception: java.lang.InterruptedExecution``` for the ```sleep(1)```

Comment: You must surround the ```TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);``` with ```try catch```

Comment: @ShaiAlon What can one usually have in that catch block ?

Comment: If anyone is still struggling with this function, make the enclosing function that calls ```sleep()``` throw InterruptedException with ```throws``` and catch it where the function is being called. @Stephane Or simply enclose that statement in a try-catch to catch the InterruptedException and print the stack trace.

Answer (score 231):

Use `Thread.sleep(1000)`;

`1000` is the number of milliseconds that the program will pause.

```java
try {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to log the InterruptedException or you will never know this thread got interrupted.

Comment: I'm curious as to what the Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); does here.

Comment: see : "Why do we have to interrupt the thread again?" here : https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html

Comment: If I read the link above correctly, `thread.sleep()` raises the interrupt flag. The try turns off the interrupt flag.  Calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` raises the interrupt flag again. If other parts of your program (e.g dependencies) rely on threading/ or sleep as well, it will be looking for this nonexistent interrupt flag.

tl;dr: Without `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` invoked, you will introduce a nightmare bug to debug if other dependencies unknowingly use Thread.sleep() in their dependencies

Comment: May be a noob question, but I don't understand why we need to catch the interrupt in the first place?

Answer (score 33):

Use this:

```java
public static void wait(int ms)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

and, then you can call this method anywhere like:

```
wait(1000);
```

Comment: What does `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` do? Why is it important?

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the `Thread.sleep()` call.

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score 7):

Use  `Thread.sleep(100);`.
The unit of time is milliseconds

For example:

```
public class SleepMessages {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws InterruptedException {
        String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };

        for (int i = 0;
             i < importantInfo.length;
             i++) {
            //Pause for 4 seconds
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            //Print a message
            System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` or `Thread.sleep(1000);` Is acceptable way to do it. In both cases you have to catch `InterruptedException`which makes your code Bulky.There is an Open Source java library called MgntUtils (written by me) that provides utility that already deals with `InterruptedException` inside. So your code would just include one line:

```
TimeUtils.sleepFor(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

See the javadoc [here](https://appdoc.app/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/com/mgnt/utils/TimeUtils.html). You can access library from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). The article explaining about the library could be found [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)

Comment: Using `catch (InterruptedException e) { /* empty */ }` is **NOT** a sensible solution here. At the very least, you should provide some log information. For more information about the subject, see https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html

Comment: @Marco13 Actually due to your comment and comments from some other people I modified the method TimeUtils.sleepFor() and now it interrupts current thread. So, it is still convenient in a way that you don't need to catch the  InterruptedException, but the interruption mechanism now works.

Answer (score 3):

There is also one more way to wait.

You can use [LockSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) methods, e.g.:

```java
LockSupport.parkNanos(1_000_000_000); // Disables current thread for scheduling at most for 1 second
```

Fortunately they don't throw any checked exception. But on the other hand according to the documentation there are more reasons for thread to be enabled:

- Some other thread invokes unpark with the current thread as the target
- Some other thread interrupts the current thread

Comment: great answer, but it won't be bad to mention spurious wake-ups as a third reason.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old post but this may help someone:
You can create a method, so whenever you need to pause you can type `pause(1000)` or any other millisecond value:

```
public static void pause(int ms) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.format("InterruptedException : %s%n", e);
    }
}
```

This is inserted just above the `public static void main(String[] args)`, inside the class. Then, to call on the method, type `pause(ms)` but replace `ms` with the number of milliseconds to pause. That way, you don't have to insert the entire try-catch statement whenever you want to pause.

Comment: Looking at the almost same answer by @Hecanet there is no `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` If it is important why is it not shown? - If it is not important why would it be inserted/omitted?