# How to test webmethods through LeanFT

Tags: leanft

I just want to know , if we are testing the webservices which are getting created while execution of the test cases ,then How LeanFT will be helpful ??

For more clarification,suppose when we execute the test case then some webmethods will be called for fetching the results fron the Backend.So,We have to validate that wether Application is calling the right webmethod or not?

So,In this scenario, how LeanFT is useful? Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

LeanFT runs in an environment. Currently either one of `C#`, `Java` or `JavaScript` (with the corresponding frameworks (e.g. `NUnit`, `TestNG` or `Jasmine`)).

As such, if you start a test in which a webservice is called, and you want LeanFT to test the behavior of this webservice, you can ***"teach"* LeanFT to wait** through various ways:

- Either through some kind of wait operation like [C# `Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx), Java's [`TimeUnit.sleep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-to-delay-in-java) or [JavaScript's `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)
- or through LeanFT's own wait logic - examples on
  [JS](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Quality-and-Testing-Blog/LeanFT-JavaScript-SDK-synchronizing-test-execution-with-the/ba-p/1600402#.WcOeMsgjHqa),
  [C#](https://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.01/HelpCenter/Content/CodeSamples_.NET/CodeEx.NETWeb.htm#hp-minitoc-item-7)
  or
  [Java](https://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.01/HelpCenter/Content/CodeSamples_Java/codeex_Java.htm#hp-minitoc-item-1)