# I want a delay in this program

Tags: java, delay

I used `'Thread'` and `'TimeUnit'` but not know how to use in the following program. I want when WIN+E execute then after some delay of 1 or 2 second next statement run. As, next statement is in for loop so it should run after 2 seconds infinite time (because of infinite for loop). You can see `ActionListener` line only.
package v;

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class V extends JPanel{
    private JButton V;
    public V() throws AWTException{
        Robot r = new Robot();
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
        V = new JButton("PUSH");
        add(V);
        V.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i=0; i>0; i++) {r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS); r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);}
        }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        V panel = new V();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("V");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }

}
```

Comment: That is, in fact, a thoroughly *finite* for-loop.

Comment: You should probably use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-to-delay-in-java)

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` might be the solution you want

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

i would go for something like this:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class V extends JPanel{
    private JButton V;
    private boolean notstarted=true;
    public V() throws AWTException{
        Robot r = new Robot();
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
        V = new JButton("PUSH");
        add(V);
        V.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(notstarted){
                notstarted=false;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS); 
                        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(StreamServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS); 
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);}
                }
            }).start();
            }
        }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        V panel = new V();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("V");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }

}
```

As you can see i have added a boolean `notstarted` to control if the function have been accessed previously, so, this way you cant run that more than one and finally i have added a `Thread` to mitigate the impact the `ActionListener` could have on the thread that call it.

Anyway there should be beeter ways to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javafx.animation.PauseTransition`

```
PauseTransition happen = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
    happen.setOnFinished(e -> {
        System.out.println("hello");
        happen.playFromStart();
    });
    happen.play();
```

Like that. It will print hello every 2 seconds. That however requires you to extend `javafx.application.Application` and I see that you don't use javafx in your program.

You can use Thread.sleep as the other answer suggests - to sleep each 2000 miliseconds (in your loop).

There is also `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask`. It allows you to do code every milisecond given in time. There is an excellent video of that here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36jbBSQd3eU