# How do you Schedule In java?

Tags: java

For example if you schedule in **Python** you just have to import time, then do `time.sleep(seconds)` and then your good to go. I've tried to do some similar things in Java, but it never worked.

Comment: Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: `java.lang.Thread.currentThread().sleep(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds));`

Comment: it looks like very similar to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104427/9081600

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new here.

I tried doing `import java.time;` then I just did `System.time.sleep(seconds)`

Comment: You can't just make up stuff that looks like something you saw in another language.  You have to actually read the documentation to see how it works in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try code sleep 3s :

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, it said:

Main.java:13: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Thread.sleep(3000);
                ^
1 error

Comment: `public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}`
please try run codea again

Comment: @huunhancit Please don't "correct" code by posting a comment, [edit] your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can user class Timer java
Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
Or use http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/