# how do I make a custom delay function with java in processing 3.4?

Tags: java, while-loop, processing, custom-function

```
float x = 0;

void setup() {
    size(200,200);
    frameRate(60);
    background(255);
}

int v = (int)random(0,width);
int b = (int)random(0,height);

void draw() {
    drawCar(v,b,50,0);
    secondDelay(5);
    v = (int)random(0,width);
    b = (int)random(0,height);
}

void drawCar(int x, int y, int thesize, int col) {
    int offset = thesize/4;

    //draw main car body
    rectMode (CENTER);
    stroke(200);
    fill(col);
    rect(x,y,thesize, thesize/2);

    //draw wheel relative to car body center
    fill(0);
    rect(x-offset,y-offset,offset,offset/2);
    rect(x+offset,y-offset,offset,offset/2);
    rect(x+offset,y+offset,offset,offset/2);
    rect(x-offset,y+offset,offset,offset/2);
}

void secondDelay(int aSecond){
    int aS;
    aS = aSecond * 60;
    while(aS > 0) {
        aS--;
    }
}
```

what I'm trying to do is make the `secondDelay()` function work as a way of delaying the `draw` function (which is a loop that updates every frame). also the frameRate itself is 60, so 60 frames per second is what `draw()` is running at.
This is done by giving the amount of seconds I want as the argument of `secondDelay(amountofseconds)`. then inside that `secondDelay()` function
it multiplies the amount of seconds by the amount of frames per second which is 60. Now i have the amount of frames that i need to wait which i put in a variable called `aS`. What i do then inside the `secondDelay()` function, is make a while loop that runs everytime it sees that variable `aS` is bigger than 0. Then i just subtract 1 from `aS` everytime it loops until it is no longer bigger than 0. That's when the amount of seconds u wanted it to delay has been delayed and then it does the whole `draw()` loop again.

That's how I explain the code that i made, but it doesn't work. Instead it is just acting like `secondDelay(5);` doesn't exist so it just creates new cars every frame. 
How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java/24104427#24104427

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to do, you have to count the frames. It the number of frames exceeds a number, which is equal the delay time span, then you have to draw a new car.
You don't need a function that delays, waits or sleeps for a while, but you need a function that tells and signals you that a period of time has passed.

Create a global frame counter (`frame_count`) and count the frames in the `secondDelay` function. If the counter exceeds `60*aSecond` then the function reset the counter to 0. If the counter is 0, then this is signaled by returning the `boolean` value true.

```
int frame_count = 0; 
boolean secondDelay(int aSecond){

    boolean signal = frame_count==0;

    if ( frame_count >= 60*aSecond ) {
        frame_count = 0;
    } else { 
        frame_count ++;
    }
    return signal;
}
```

Every time when the `secondDelay` returns true and so gives you the signal, then you have to draw a new car in the `draw` function:

```
void draw() {

    if ( secondDelay(5) ) {
        drawCar(v,b,50,0);
        v = (int)random(0,width);
        b = (int)random(0,height);
    }
}
```