# Login fail attempt delay

Tags: authentication, frontend, delay, backend, ddos

I've read some about login security and I've found a good practice for preventing rapid-fire login attempts. The idea is apply a short time delay that increases with the number of failed attempts, like:

- 1 failed attempt = no delay
- 2 failed attempts = 2 sec delay
- 3 failed attempts = 4 sec delay
- 4 failed attempts = 8 sec delay
- 5 failed attempts = 16 sec delay
- etc.

I understand the idea, but I would like to know how to code this. 
Where and how should I put the delay? In the backend or in the frontend? I think it would be in the backend... But, how could I do that? How can I stop the current attempt for any seconds and continue? Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that I should put it in the backend using some method that delay the current thread like it's been seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java).

If I do that, it won't affect the other users, isn't it?