# How do i actively(instantly) check the value of a textbox in a JFrame Form WITHOUT buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

I want to be able to type into a textbox and as the user types into the textbox i want the program to automatically read the textbox without the need of clicking a button.

Example:
**User types:** "abcd"
and as the user typed it, the program displayed the corresponding number to each letter.

**Program outputs:** "1234"

As in: a -> 1; b -> 2; etc.

Im using "*private void mycode()*"
to write my code. I saw that if I made it static I could use **java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104427/12577450) but then *mycode()* would not work right with my variables.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DocumentListener` class.

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 123;
    private JTextField field1, field2;

    public MyFrame() {
        super.setSize(600, 400);
        super.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 400));
        super.setResizable(false);
        field1 = new JTextField();
        field2 = new JTextField();
        super.add(field1);
        super.add(field2);
        field1.setLocation(0, 0);
        field1.setSize(600, 200);
        field2.setLocation(0, 200);
        field2.setSize(600, 200);
        field2.setEditable(false);
        super.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        field1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              f();
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              f();
            }
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              f();
            }
            public void f(){
                String new_str = "";
                for (char c : field1.getText().toCharArray()) {
                    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                        new_str += (int) (c - 'a' + 1); // is this what you want?
                    else
                        new_str += c;
                }
                field2.setText(new_str);
                field2.setBounds(0, 200, 600, 200);
            }
        });
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        super.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! What i want is to use the value being typed into the textbox instantly as it is being typed. I tried using a "for loop" but the program tends to crash.

Comment: You can use the `insertUpdate` method for that