# How to make a wait period between the lines of code

Tags: java

I want to create a wait period between code like this:

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessgeDialog(null, "2 hours left");
// Wait for 2 hours
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 hours ago");
```

But i don't know how to make this wait period, i will try all answers and chose the best one but please answer me.

Comment: basically, you want a Timer to hold your code for 2 hours, and after two hours print the second line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a delay in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java)

Comment: That helped too, thanks #ruohola

Comment: Don't let a Thread sleep for two hours. Use timers or similar constructs instead to execute specific actions in the future. For example have a look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you use `Thread.sleep` method, here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html):

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessgeDialog(null, "2 hours left");
// Wait for 2 hours
Thread.sleep(7200000);
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 hours ago");
```

you can either throw `InterruptedException` inside your method, or you can handle it using `try-catch`.

Comment: Thanks #Mohsen_Fatemi , That helped alot

Comment: But, what 7200000 is, a millisecond or a microsecond or what ?

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedKamal if you see the documentation, you'll see it's in `millisecond`.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers suggest using `Thread.sleep()`. I suppose it could work but it blocks the current thread. Usually you don't want that.

You should use instead more robust solution which is a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and its `schedule` method. Something like this should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    long delay = 2L;
    executorService.schedule(App::myTask, delay, TimeUnit.HOURS);
}

private static void myTask() {
    //whatever you want to execute after delay
    System.out.println("Running");
}
```

The code inside of the `myTask` method will execute in some other thread after 2h delay.

Comment: Actually, just adding `executorService.shutdown()` at the end of the `main` method above should work.  I'm just dumb :).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```java
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessgeDialog(null, "2 hours left");
// Wait for 2 hours
try {
    Thread.sleep(7200000);// Time duration in miliseconds
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 hours ago");
```

Alternatively, as @user2478398 suggested

```java
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessgeDialog(null, "2 hours left");
// Wait for 2 hours
TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(2L);
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 hours ago");
```

Comment: `120_000` = 2 minutes.  `TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(2L);` would be more readable, less error prone, and actually sleep the correct duration.  That said, sleeping for 2 hours is a horrible idea for a `Thread`.

Comment: I am making a time table, and a setting to say how much to wait then give an alarm, so if the user wanted for examples 2 hours, it should wait 2 hours and then give an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

> Add delay like this:

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessgeDialog(null, "2 hours left");
TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(2); // Wait for 2 hours
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 hours ago");
```