# how to run a code 60 times per second in java

Tags: java, frame-rate

if I don't control the number of times per second my code executes, when I add a line, the program varies and I have to adjust the constants again. (translated by Google)
My code running out of control:

```
public builder(){
    while(true)
        stepEvent();
}
private void stepEvent() {
    setOfActions();
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: I believe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just one way to do it(it's very long but VERY precise - I recommend it for game development). In this case I'm using the `run()` method from the Runnable interface to execute the code.

```
public void run(){
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    while(true){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while(delta >= 1){
            the code you want to be executed 
            delta--;
            }
        } 
   }
```

**Explanation Line by Line:**

Basically, I store the current time in nanoseconds in `lastTime`. Then in `ns` I store 1/60th of a second in nanoseconds and create a variable `delta`.

After this, I go inside the infinite while loop(it doesn't have to be infinite) and store the current time in nanoseconds once again in `now`. This is to take into account the amount of time that took the computer to go from the `lastTime` declaration line to the while loop line.

After doing all this, I add to `delta` the difference of `now` and `lastTime` divided by the 1/60th of a second(`ns`) I mentioned. This means that every time `delta` is equal to 1, 1/60th of a second will have passed.

Right after this, I make `lastTime` be the same as `now`. In the while loop that comes afterwards I check if delta is equal or greater than 1 and then in there you should put all the code you want to be executed 60 times per second. Don't forget to substract 1 from `delta` so it doesn't loop endlessly.

Analyze the code thoroughly and see if you can understand it. If you can't, I'll clarify further. I insist that this is just one possible way to do it, but there are many more ways.

Note: In some cases, you will never even need `delta`, but it is very helpful for some purposes.

Credit for the code: Most of this code(at least where I got it & learned it) is extracted from [TheCherno's Game Programming Series](https://youtu.be/2SUtcxJYN6k)

Have a great day!

Comment: Code as presented doesn't work - try putting a System.out.println into the inner while to demonstrate it doesn't do anything. It never goes into that section because delta is always < 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        // number of ms in 1/60 of a second
        // there will be some rounding error here,
        // not sure if that's acceptable for your use case
        int ms = 1000 / 60;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, ms);
     }
}

class SayHello extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you have to execute your `stepEvent` every 17 ms.

With the assumption you want to run sequentially, you could stop the execution during a defined period by using `Thread.sleep(millis , nanos)`. In this case, we will stop the thread 17ms minus the `stepEvent` execution time (think to add condition to avoid negative value in sleep function)

```
long startedTime;
for(;;){
    startedTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    stepEvent();
    Thread.sleep(17 - System.currentTimeMillis() + startedTime);
}
```

Otherwise you can use the `ScheduledExecutorService` which allows you to schedule code to run periodically at fixed time intervals (or after a specified delay). In this case, you can execute your step at a fixed rate every 17ms.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(YourClass::stepEvent, 0, 17, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

You can also configure to use severals thread with `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool`

Comment: what is it for :: ? (Thanks for the great contribution)

Comment: YourClass::stepEvent is to point your function `class YourClass { public static void stepEvent() {...}}`