# How to stop a car every 3 seconds and continue driving again

Tags: java, oop, scheduler

I am a bit new to Java and OOP. My question is:
I have an abstract class called Car with drive method. There is another subclass of it, called `AntiqueCar`. Antique car stops working when it drives for 3 seconds. So it will stop after 3 seconds but then continue driving again. (I think that I could override drive method in AntiqueCar class) I tried many things, but I just could manage to stop the antique car but could not make it work again.

Here is drive method:

```
public void drive(Dimension2D gameBoardSize) {
        if (this.crunched) {
            return;
        }
        double maxX = gameBoardSize.getWidth();
        double maxY = gameBoardSize.getHeight();
        // calculate delta between old coordinates and new ones based on speed and
        // direction
        double deltaX = this.speed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.direction));
        double deltaY = this.speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.direction));
        double newX = this.position.getX() + deltaX;
        double newY = this.position.getY() + deltaY;

        // calculate position in case the boarder of the game board has been reached
        if (newX < 0) {
            newX = -newX;
            this.direction = MAX_ANGLE - this.direction;
        } else if (newX + this.size.getWidth() > maxX) {
            newX = 2 * maxX - newX - 2 * this.size.getWidth();
            this.direction = MAX_ANGLE - this.direction;
        }

        if (newY < 0) {
            newY = -newY;
            this.direction = HALF_ANGLE - this.direction;
            if (this.direction < 0) {
                this.direction = MAX_ANGLE + this.direction;
            }
        } else if (newY + this.size.getHeight() > maxY) {
            newY = 2 * maxY - newY - 2 * this.size.getHeight();
            this.direction = HALF_ANGLE - this.direction;
            if (this.direction < 0) {
                this.direction = MAX_ANGLE + this.direction;
            }
        }
        // set coordinates
        this.position = new Point2D(newX, newY);
    }
```

Then here is the AntiqueCar class:

```
public class AntiqueCar extends Car {

    private static final String ANTIQUE_CAR_IMAGE_FILE = "antiquecar.gif";
    // this car is middle-speeded. Not so fast, not so slow.
    private static final int MIN_SPEED_FAST_CAR = 2;
    private static final int MAX_SPEED_FAST_CAR = 7;

    public AntiqueCar(Dimension2D gameBoardSize) {
        super(gameBoardSize);
        setMinSpeed(MIN_SPEED_FAST_CAR);
        setMaxSpeed(MAX_SPEED_FAST_CAR);
        setRandomSpeed();
        setIconLocation(ANTIQUE_CAR_IMAGE_FILE);

    }
```

Appreciate any kind of help, thanks!

Comment: Just implement "public void drive(Dimension2D gameBoardSize) {" in your AntiqueCar. You can also use super.drive to call the code in the abstract Car - and just add your delay code / don't drive code to it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [override method in derived class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html). So you can call method from the base class and then just [sleep it for three seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java):

```
public class AntiqueCar extends Car {

    public void drive(Dimension2D gameBoardSize) {
        super.drive(gameVoardSize);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);    
    }

}
```