# How can I make my Java application wait a time before process the next line?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Im making a Selenium automation and I already tried this but no success:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
```

and

```
driver.wait(2000);
```

Comment: Hello i found a Post it may includes the Solution to your problem.
[how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java)

Comment: Write what error do you get or where exactly the problem is? Maybe attach some method. All these approaches are working, but without context, it is difficult to identify what you exactly need and how we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

**Code:**

```java
System.out.println( "Hello" );

try{
    Thread.sleep( 1000 );
    System.out.println( "sleep 1 second" );
}catch( InterruptedException e ){
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
}

System.out.println( "World" );
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
sleep 1 second
World
```

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In Katalon you can use:

```
WebUI.delay(GlobalVariable.DELAY_1_SECONDS)
```

In Sellenium you can use:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Or:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
```

You can find more example in this [post of Sadhvi Singh](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/types-of-waits-in-selenium/).