# Is there any way to wait 10 seconds and then execute the next line of code in Java?

Tags: java

In my program, I try to find a css address then I do some other computations.
I need to execute the next line of my code if FolderTest1 is null.

```
WebElement FolderTest1 = driverChrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-51846c7840975f97241367"));
driverChrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is confusing, but to answer your *title*, yes, just put `try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch (InterruptedException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }` before the line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delay a Java program for a few seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342651/how-can-i-delay-a-java-program-for-a-few-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
WebElement FolderTest1 = driverChrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-51846c7840975f97241367"));
if(FolderTest1 == null)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie)
    {}    
}
```

Comment: no. In first line, if the program couldn't find the css address it does not do anything!!

Comment: I mean, I want to execute the rest of the code after 10 seconds, with or without finding css address.