# Stay on a page for 30 minutes ,then perform a operations (Webdriver-Java)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a scenario where I login to an application, perform a download operation then wait (stay) on that page for 30 minutes, then again perform the download operation.

Is `implicitwait` for 30 minutes is feasible in the scenario? Is there any better option?

Comment: Could you please clarify why you need to stay on the page for 30 minutes? To have your session expired?

Comment: tell us why your want to wait or 30 minutes, this doesn't sound like good design in the first place.

Comment: @ViktorMalyi  This is the requirement of the team. We want to observe for how long page can be kept idle before continuing with the next scenario.

Comment: Some sort of setting defines the session time out. Instead of waiting the configured time. Change the setting and test it with a shorter time. These kind of test are other quite bad to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An implicit wait is to tell `WebDriver` to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. It wont be helpful for current scenario.

You can use [`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) or [`TimeUnit.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep%28long%29) like

```
try {
     TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(30);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //Handle exception
}
```

For more information : [I'm unable to use Thread.sleep(x) or wait(): java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342651/how-can-i-delay-a-java-program-for-a-few-seconds)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use the implicit wait. Use `Thread.Sleep(30*60*1000);` instead. This will sleep the main thread of your tests until the specified value of milliseconds pass.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://yourapplication.com");
Thread.Sleep(30*60*1000); 
// Download Files
```

Comment: Its 30 minutes, so it should probably be `Thread.sleep(30* 1000 * 60)`

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely correct. Thank you for the suggestion.