# How to have a break of a few seconds in execution of program

Tags: java

This question might sound strange but I'm interested to know if somehow i can have a break of a few seconds in execution of a program.For example when you have a simple for() for printing out the elemnts of an array,the elements will be printed all directcly.I was wondering if it is possible to print like the first element then after a break of 2 second print the second one and so on until the last one.Is something like this possible?

Comment: You should check out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342651/how-can-i-delay-a-java-program-for-a-few-seconds

Comment: Thread.sleep(2000); ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: You could use Thread.currentThread().sleep() but this is not guaranteed to sleep for exactly 2 seconds. Could be more. Or you could use a while loop that subtracts from the current time the time at which the last value was printed and see if the difference is 2 seconds and then print the next value. This is a busy wait while the other option with sleep() leaves your processor free to do other tasks.

Comment: However, Java's time resolution is about (literally) a thousand times better than C++, and on a normal PC lies somewhere in the vicinity of 50 nanoseconds.

Comment: Didn't wait it to seem like self-promotion, so I linked the duplicate to the earlier question. But I would recommend [my approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24104427/2071828).

Comment: @JayC667 - That doesn't change the fact that sleep() depends on the underlying OS's scheduler which doesn't have to be as accurate as java expects it to be.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - From the OP's exercise, it seems a ScheduledExecutorService seems to be too much of an ask though that would be the right way to go if your task is more meaningful than printing a single number.

Comment: @user3493289 given the OP wants to wait for two **seconds**, waiting for a few extra **microseconds** is unlikely to make a different. Checking the current time would not solve this, as the resolution of the system clock is no better. `System.nanoTime` would be the only way to make your solution more accurate.

Comment: @user3493289 drift likely isn't a problem in this case. I was more referring to `TimeUnit.sleep` rather than `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I didnt disagree with you. Just said that ExecutorService would be an overkill for this exercise. Anyway TimeUnit.sleep internally calls Thread.sleep(). All that I said was that sleep() would be a better solution as the accuracy of 2 seconds is not important in this case and is a better solution than subtracting from the current time as it avoids busy waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the Thread.sleep().

```
for (...) {
    //print the element
    try {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //do things with exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.sleep(1000)` method in for loop:

```
public class JavaApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints from 0 to 9,  one number per second.

```
run:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
**BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with the function sleep .

```
Thread.sleep(4000); // 4000 = 4 second
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Try this :

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

In this way, the program will pause for 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: When that exception occurs?

Comment: @EbraHim : This exception is thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.currentThread.sleep(time in ms);`

Comment: Please add some explanaition of the code or at least a link to the programming reference or guide.